# Microsoft Teams chat bot exercise from Microsoft Learn

Tags: bots, microsoft-teams, azure-bot-service

I am taking the following Microsoft Learning path and I get an error when I add the app to Teams.
[MS-600: Develop apps for Microsoft Teams - Associate](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/training/paths/m365-msteams-associate/)

[image: Teams Error]

I used dev tools to inspect the process and received the following errors. one solution I read was to make sure the bot had the team's channel, which it did.

[image: dev tools error]

The error it gives is 502 bot returned an unsuccessful status code NotFound, errorCode: 1008, errorSubCode: underfin

verified the secret for the bot and even created a new one with no such luck.
Ngrok url is correct for the bot endpoint in azure

Comment: I ended up fixing it. I did not have the ngrok name in the .env under PUBLIC_HOSTNAME